# How to implement clock page replacement algorithm in C? Not C++

Tags: c, algorithm, process, operating-system, clock

I'm new to C and I'm having trouble implementing this program its suppose to simulate
the clock page replacement algorithm for swapping pages in and out of memory of a process.

I don't quite know where to begin with implementing this simulation. I'm suppose to read a file for pages numbers 0-99 and then from there use the Clock page replacement algorithm to 
simulate page replacements. Could anyone steer me in the right direction, I have been reading c by discovery over the weekend so I could learn the language. Any help would be great. Thanks. Attached is the algorithm.[image: Clock Page Replacement]

Comment: Why is the algorithm not optimal. I'm still working on it, but I'm just wondering why this algorithm isn't optimal for a simulation of this page replacement algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of the data to store isn't clear, is it a bit field or something else? Is the case of a bit field, each data item would be allocated as a primitive integer type (like unsigned int, or preferably uint32_t). In that case, you would use the bit wise operators to set, clear or check a bit.

In the case where the data is something else, you would use a struct to define each data item and the bit can be represented as a bool.

In both cases, the whole "clock" can be allocated as an array of items, which you iterate through with a simple for loop. The pseudo code posted next to the clock isn't ideal: use a for loop whenever the number of items is known in advance. There's no need for a "clock pointer", use the loop iterator.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and implement what you said. I'll come back to you if I have problem with it. Thank you so much, mean a lot to me. :) Your implementation seems a heck of a lot easier. So, anyway. I'll come back with my code.